# Sum of Two Continuous Random Variables

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with common PDF.

$f_X(x)=f_Y(y)=e^{-x}$, for all $x, y > 0$

I have set up the integral according to the formula for convolution for two continuous random variables. I am unsure whether the upper bound for the integral is equal to $Z$ itself. The lower bound is obviously zero.

Let $Z=2X+Y$.

Can anyone assist in figuring out how to set up the integrals with the right upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: What convolution formula are you using?

Comment: Nitin: Yes they are.

Comment: Andre: fZ(z)= ∫zx=0fX(x)fY(z−x)dx, with upper bound infinity, lower bound negative infinity.

Comment: That's fine, but then you will first have to find the density function of $2X$ (not hard).

Comment: Yeah just make it z-2x, not hard at all. thanks man!

Comment: On your deleted question, I was just about to remark that you computed the variance of the "uniform" incorrectly. You seem to have summed the squares and divided by $6$. We need to subtract $(E(X))^2$ from that for the variance.

Comment: Yes, I realized how stupid my mistake was. For some reason I kept on calculating the second moment and was confused as to why I had no luck. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

The general idea is that $X$ has a probability $f_X(x)\,\Delta x$ of being between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$, so $2X$ has the same probability of being between $2x$ and $2x+2\Delta x$.  $Y$, meanwhile, has a probability $f_Y(z-2x)\,\Delta x$ of being between $z-2x-\Delta x$ and $z-2x$, so it has a probability $2f_Y(z-2x)\,\Delta x$ of being between $z-2x-2\Delta x$ and $z-2x$ (since the "window" is twice as wide).

We can therefore write, in the limit,

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^{z/2} 2f_X(x) f_Y(z-2x) \, dx
$$

since we must have $X \leq z/2$ in order to permit $Z = z$.

Comment: Good explanation of the "why."

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, since it does not use a convolution. (The convolution approach has been very well explained by Brian Tung.)

We will find the cdf of $Z$, that is, $\Pr(Z\le z)$. Draw the line $\ell$ with equation $2x+y=z$. Then, for $z\gt 0$, $\Pr(Z\le z)$ is equal to the probability $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of the first quadrant below line $\ell$. Let $T$ be this triangle. Then
$$F_Z(z)=\iint_T e^{-x}e^{-y}\,dx\,dy.$$
Express this integral as the  iterated integral
$$\int_{x=0}^{z/2} e^{-x}\left(\int_{y=0}^{z-2x} e^{-y}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
For the density, calculate the iterated integral, then differentiate. Alternately, just calculate the inner integral, and differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: I do find this approach much easier as it allows one to visualize the answer. The only downside is that I lack experience in drawing lines with more than two variables. However that is something I should learn. Thanks!

Comment: I answered in the full expectation that Brian Tung's very good answer would be the one accepted. My only reason for answering is that I like to stress the geometry. I would be much more comfortable if you withdrew your acceptance.